# Nearest-neighbor algorithm with directions (left / right / top / bottom)

Tags: algorithm, math, optimization, data-structures, geometry

Having *n* random points in 2D geometry, for each point `p` I need to find 4 *(or less if not exists)* closest points *(*`qa`*,*`qb`*,*`qc`*,*`qd`*)*, where *qa* is the closest ***left-top*** point, *qb* is the closest ***right-top*** point, *qc* is the closest ***left-bottom*** point and *qd* is the closest ***right-bottom*** point to point *p*. Having same *x* coordinate is considered as left, having same *y* coordinate is considered as bottom.

What would be the best ***data structure*** to store point coordinates and their nearest-neighbor references? What ***algorithm*** would be the fastest or the most performed?

Note: This issue is far more then nearest-neighbor algorithm, as for each point 4 neighbor points are needed.

Comment: Is this homework? If so, add the `homework` tag.

Comment: Suppose you have a bunch of points arranged around the point `p` in a perfect circle. How do you choose between them?

Comment: Not putting this as an answer because I'm only referencing the data structure, but personally, I would use a linked list. Where each node is a point, and its connected to its closest neighbors. This will create a web that you can reference. As far as efficient construction, I'd have to think about that for a little bit lol

Comment: @MarkRansom - If there are more points with same distance, then I would do subsorting by y coordinate

Comment: @Jlange - I strongly believe that data structure will be set by algorithm.

Comment: Will you insert/delete/move points? From a given starting point is it required that each point have to be reachable from the starting point?

Comment: @biziclop - No delete, no move, but insert is very likely. Points don't have to be reachable from starting point. Actually, there might be set some max distance limit, so if there is no point close enough, it can be null.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try a space filling curve and a quadtree data structure. A space filling curve reduces the 2 dimension to 1 dimension and it works best with power of 2 grids.  A quadtree divides the plane into 4 quads. A space filling curve is mathematical function taking 2 variables and gives 1 number as result. It can have also 3,4,5 variables but the most simple is with 2. Because it gives 1 number and takes 2 variables it can help for questions with 2 dimensions or more.

1. http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/9694.tuning-spatial-point-data-queries-in-sql-server-2012.aspx
2. https://www.google.com/search?q=nearest+neigbor+search+space+filling+curve

[image]

Comment: How can space filling curve help with distance calculation?

Comment: It would tranform `(x,y)` to `z`, but such `z` value is not going to help to find the nearest neighbor in each of 4 quads.

Comment: There is no center point. I need to find neigbhor to each point. I would need to create space filling curve for each point and once some point is added, wash out all data and start again - that is not right way for my task.

Answer (score 1):

Use a k-dim tree index (in this case k=2) so a quad tree. This should allow you to efficiently search the space to the left,right,up and down of your point. You can probably formulate a query in a dmbs for this but conceptually I would search the points own "quad" and then depending on the position of the point in the quad we can know if we found the nearest point in one direction or not. Then we know which quads to search for the rest of the points.

Since you are doing this for each point you know there exists symmetry i.e. point P1 has P2 as nearest left neighbor so P2 has P1 as nearest right neighbor. So update the point objects accordingly.

Comment: This, you are essentially performing a k-d tree search but just starting from 2 levels down already. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K-d_tree